# How to dynamically add MaximumValue for RangeValidator in GridView using c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have this RangeValidator

```
    <asp:RangeValidator ID="MarksValidation" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Invalid marks" ValidationGroup="Validation" Type="Integer" ControlToValidate="subject_marks" MinimumValue="-1" MaximumValue='' ></asp:RangeValidator>
<asp:TextBox ID="subject_marks" ControlStyle-CssClass="wide" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("subject") %>' />
```

Now i want calculate max marks in c# in then assign that to MaximumValue of the RangeValidator.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `MaximumValue` property in code behind with the expression you want.

```
MarksValidation.MaximumValue = expression;
```

Example:

```
MarksValidation.MaximumValue = 50*SomeValue;
```

**Edit, based on comments, as validator is in GridView**

```
protected void gvUserInfo_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
   {
       RangeValidator rv = (RangeValidator)e.Row.FindControl("MarksValidation");
       rv.MaximumValue = 50*Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "ColumnFromDatabase"));;

   }
}
```

Comment: MarksValidation does not exist in current context.

Comment: Remove MaximumValue from html and make sure your page gets compile and you are writing in code behind of aspx page contain the validator

Comment: Also make sure you are writing code in some method like page_load as it should be accessible.

Comment: Actually the validator is for  textbox which is inside Gridview. And I know we to access using findControl. But i don't how to access the RangeValidator using FindControl.

Comment: It is same as accessing any other control you have to give id